# Unable to Change the Android App Name on Crashlytics

Tags: android, crashlytics, google-fabric, fabric.io

When I uses gradle command `assembleAlpha crashlyticsUploadDistributionAlpha` on my android studio project and I installs the alpha version via `Beta by Chrashlytics` app, the app name of my app isn't good.

On android studio I configured my project like that:

```
applicationId "com.mobile.example"
```

`

```
app
   |-src
   |   |-beta
   |   |    |-res
   |   |       |-values
   |   |          |-strings.xml (app_name 'Example Beta')
   |   |-main
   |   |    |-res
   |   |       |-values
   |   |          |-strings.xml (app_name 'Example')
`

app.gradle:

`android {
    ...
    buildTypes {
       beta {
         debug {
             applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
             buildConfigField "boolean", "REPORT_CRASHES", "false"
         }
         release {
             minifyEnabled false
             proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
             signingConfig signingConfigs.release
             debuggable false
         }
    }
}
```

`

On fabric.io dashboard, the app name for com.mobile.example.beta is setted on `Example Beta` and `Example`for packageName: com.mobile.example

But when I download/install my app, the app name is always `Example`

Do you know what is wrong on my configuration?

Comment: Mike from Fabric here - are you concerned on the package name of the app being installed or the name of it? What name do you see in your Fabric dashboard and AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: I'm concerned for the name of the app being installed. On my dashboard, the name is setted to `Example Beta` (this is for the package com.mobile.example.beta)
What do you want to know about the AndroidManifest?

Comment: In the AndroidManifest under android:label field in your application node in AndroidManifest.xml - what value do you see.

Comment: The value is:  android:label="@string/app_name"

Comment: I think you'll need to reach out to support(at)fabric(dot)io so we can dig further into this with logs.

Answer (score 1):

Note: You must be an Admin in your organization to update an app’s name.

To rename your app, head to your app’s settings then select the app whose name you want to change and click on the edit button to the left of the current name. Make your changes and then click on the blue checkmark to save them.

[This snippet](https://gist.github.com/tyvsmith/6188014) allows overriding the package name that Crashlytics discovers and reports